# JSON Can not construct instance of JSONConcatination: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to create a Map with another Map of values using the following JSON String:

```
"{\"conditionField\":\"myFieldName\",\"conditionValue\":\"myFieldValue\",\"concatenationValues\":[\"fieldValue1\",\"fieldValue2\",\"fieldValue3\"]}"
```

and getting the following JsonMappingException when i try converting it to a POJO:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of JSONConcatination: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"conditionField":"myFieldName","conditionValue":"myFieldValue","concatenationValues":["fieldValue1","fieldValue2","fieldValue3"]}')
 at [Source: "{\"conditionField\":\"myFieldName\",\"conditionValue\":\"myFieldValue\",\"concatenationValues\":[\"fieldValue1\",\"fieldValue2\",\"fieldValue3\"]}"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

using the following code:

```
private final Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> jsonResources = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>(); 



ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();           
JSONConcatination jsonConcatination = mapper.readValue(json, JSONConcatination.class);
Map<String, List<String>> values = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
values.put(jsonConcatination.getConditionValue(), jsonConcatination.getConcatenationValues());
jsonResources.put(jsonConcatination.getConditionField(), values);


@Data
public class JSONConcatination {

    private String conditionField;

    private String conditionValue;

    private List<String> concatenationValues;

}
```

Comment: how you are reading this json

Comment: I'm reading it from an oracle database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON String in invalid, First make it a valid one using following replace operation, this will remove start and end quotes as well as backslash in json string.
Now jackson will consider this as a valid json string.

```
json = json.replaceAll("^\"|\"$|\\\\", "");
```

then this will work.